# tkinter Entry not spanning columns

Tags: python, tkinter

this code currently produces:

[image]
and
[image]

I want the Username to start in aligned with First name and password and finish at last name and confirm two columns spans.

as you can see the **Username** entry only spans one column even thouh *columnspan* is set to 2. I need any solutions to fix this. Thanks

```
from tkinter import *

Master = ()
Master.attributes("-fullscreen", True)

Page = Frame(Master)
Page.place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.5, anchor = "center")

FirstnameEntry = Entry(Page); FirstnameEntry.insert(0, "First name"); FirstnameEntry.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
FirstnameEntry.bind("<FocusIn>", lambda event: FirstnameEntry.get() == "First name" and FirstnameEntry.delete(0, END))
FirstnameEntry.bind("<FocusOut>", lambda event: FirstnameEntry.get() == "" and FirstnameEntry.insert(0, "First name"))

LastnameEntry = Entry(Page); LastnameEntry.insert(0, "Last name"); LastnameEntry.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
LastnameEntry.bind("<FocusIn>", lambda event: LastnameEntry.get() == "Last name" and LastnameEntry.delete(0, END))
LastnameEntry.bind("<FocusOut>", lambda event: LastnameEntry.get() == "" and LastnameEntry.insert(0, "Last name"))

UsernameEntry = Entry(Page); UsernameEntry.insert(0, "Username"); UsernameEntry.grid(row = 1, column = 0, columspan = 2)
UsernameEntry.bind("<FocusIn>", lambda event: UsernameEntry.get() == "Username" and UsernameEntry.delete(0, END))
UsernameEntry.bind("<FocusOut>", lambda event: UsernameEntry.get() == "" and UsernameEntry.insert(0, "Username"))

PasswordEntry = Entry(Page); PasswordEntry.insert(0, "Password"); PasswordEntry.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
PasswordEntry.bind("<FocusIn>", lambda event: PasswordEntry.get() == "Password" and PasswordEntry.delete(0, END))
PasswordEntry.bind("<FocusOut>", lambda event: PasswordEntry.get() == "" and PasswordEntry.insert(0, "Password"))

ConfirmEntry = Entry(Page); ConfirmEntry.insert(0, "Confirm"); ConfirmEntry.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
ConfirmEntry.bind("<FocusIn>", lambda event: ConfirmEntry.get() == "Confirm" and ConfirmEntry.delete(0, END))
ConfirmEntry.bind("<FocusOut>", lambda event: ConfirmEntry.get() == "" and ConfirmEntry.insert(0, "Confirm"))

Master.mainloop()
```

Comment: `UsernameEntry.grid(row = 1, column = 0, columspan = 2, sticky = 'ew')`

Comment: In the second picture it looks like it's spanning it to me. Are you asking about how to get it to stretch to fill the two columns?

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `sticky = "we"` modifier

in the code:

`.grid(row = 1, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = "we")`

Answer (score 0):

In line 3. You are missing widget.

Change this:

```
Master = ()
```

to:

```
Master = Tk()
```

And in line 17 followde by @Alex Jando.

Result:

[image]